# Are computer programming questions centered on e-book creation/consumption on-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration, scope, off-topic, on-topic

A question asking about a way to accomplish some e-book specific task in a programming language seems to be on-topic both here, and on StackOverflow/Programmers.

Example: [this one](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/220/are-there-perl-modules-recommended-for-reading-and-creating-epub-files).

Are such questions on-topic here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say **yes**. This site is intended both for users of e-book and e-reader software as well as publishers creating content for e-books and e-readers. Therefore, at least from a broad point-of-view, programming questions should be on-topic.

Comment: I agree as long as the question is not what is wrong with my code.  That belongs on SO.  Questions of "right" way to accomplish some ebook programming task belong on Programmers.  But questions that are primarily about Ebooks that have some programming overlap should be fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I also would say yes although that particular is not the greatest.